How to handle intraday risk when evaluating performance with PnL/VaR?
When evaluating a proprietary trader's performance at the end of the year, it's common to use the PnL/VaR ratio as a key metric. From what I understand, the VaR used as the denominator should typically be the ex-ante estimate, often calculated at the end of each day based on the trader's open positions.
However, I’m curious about how to handle significant intraday risk exposures. Specifically, do firms evaluate risk at a more granular level (e.g., hourly) and then scale this to a daily VaR? Or is it common practice to use a realized PnL distribution, such as taking the trader’s historical PnL and computing quantiles to assess risk?
I would greatly appreciate insights on the common industry practices, particularly in the context of proprietary trading firms. How do practitioners address these considerations when assessing performance metrics?

To add more context, I am thinking a situation where a trader flattens 90% of his positions before market close, so the daily VaR computed at the end of the day does not reflect the risk taken during the day

From my experience, even historical VaR is on an ex-ante basis,

Or is it common practice to use a realized PnL distribution, such as taking the trader’s historical PnL and computing quantiles to assess risk?

this is not used. What historical VaR is - is using changes in market variables to revalue instruments in their own manner, and the returns generated through the revaluation are ranked and the appropriate percentile is taken to be the historical VaR value. This was done on a daily basis and annualized (in my experience).
If we are talking about

Specifically, do firms evaluate risk at a more granular level (e.g., hourly) and then scale this to a daily VaR?

I usually hear people use 5-minute returns, but this could be subject to microstructure effects, and I am not exactly an expert on it. But if I had to, I would use 5-minute returns and then scale it up to a day.
